# Returning characters in a string, Returning consonants issues

Tags: java

Create a program that reads a string entered by the user and then determines and prints how many of each lowercase vowel (a, e, i, o, and u) appear in the entire string.  Have a separate counter for each vowel.  Also, count and print the number of non-vowel characters.

When I created my program, the vowels return fine, but the consonant values are always off. Say the user inputs "I am feeling very cold today", the program returns the value of consonants as **19** when it should return it as **14**.
Could you take a look at my program and help me determine why the returned consonant value is always wrong?

```java
package CharacterCount;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CharacterCount {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 0, e = 0, x = 0;
        int o = 0, u = 0, consonant = 0;
        String str;
        
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Enter a string");
            str = scan.nextLine();
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            
            if (c== 'a' || c== 'A') a++;            
            else if (c== 'e' || c== 'E') e++;           
            else if (c== 'i' || c== 'I') x++;           
            else if (c== 'o' || c== 'O') o++;           
            else if (c== 'u' || c== 'U') u++;       
            else consonant++;   
        }
        
        System.out.println("a: " + a + "\n" +
        "e: " + e + "\n" +
        "i: " + x + "\n" +
        "o: " + o + "\n" +
        "u: " + u + "\n" +
        "consonants:" + consonant);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: "Also, count and print the number of non-vowel characters."   VERSUS "but the consonant values are always off"   These are not the same.  Are supposed to be counting `non-vowels`, or only `consonants`?  Decide, or clarify the assignment with your teacher and/or instructions.

Comment: The number of spaces between words is equal to five.

Answer (score 0):

looks like your program would currently consider a space character as a consonant... so you need to check for the space before incrementing your consonant variable

Comment: also you could consider using equalsIgnoreCase to save checking lower and upper case vowels